# Issue with checked checkbox in Liferay/Alloy UI

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

I have a form which has the checkbox. I am saving the check box value as true/false based on selecting of the check box. If I open the form in a edit mode, I am able to get the value from DB as true or false. Now I get the value as true I need to show the checked checkbox in my form OR If the value is false then I need to show the unchecked checkbox. please give me some suggestions.

```
<%= user.isadmin() %> // here I am getting either true or false
```

Based on above value I need to check or uncheck the check box,

```
<aui:input type="checkbox" name="isadmin" label="Is Admin"></aui:input>
```

If I use,

```
 <aui:input type="checkbox" name="isadmin" label="Is Admin" checked="<%= user.isadmin()>"></aui:input>
```

Though `user.isadmin()` value is true, I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following way for checking checkbox based on the value of `user.isadmin()`

```
<% String checked = user.isadmin() ? "checked" : "" %>
<aui:input type="checkbox" name="isadmin" label="Is Admin" <%=checked %>></aui:input>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, you get an error when compiling the JSP page. You should instead used **checked="true"**, or **checked="<%=myVar%>"** where _myVar_ is a boolean.